# Returned variable from a class function produces an error " Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind()"

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo

I have a class dbConnect

```
class dbConnect
{
    private $dbh;

    public function getConnection() 
    {
        $dbhost=DB_HOST;
        $dbuser=DB_USERNAME;
        $dbpass=DB_PASSWORD;
        $dbname=DB_NAME;
        $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $this->dbh;
    }
}
```

Calling function is

```
function returnValidClientId($userClient)
{
        $sql_query = "SELECT clientName from ValidClients where clientId=:userClient";//Line 1

        $db_connect_var = new dbConnect;//Line 2

        $dbh = $db_connect_var->getConnection();//Line 3

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql_query);//Line 4

        $stmt -> bind("userClient",$userClient);//Line 5

        $stmt -> execute();//Line 6

        $clients= $stmt->fetchObjects();//Line 7
}
```

Upon using the class dbConnect from the function returnValidClientId, i get an error " Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind()" in line 4

But if i write the function getConnection without any class implementation, the above code works fine..

Can someone explain where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no `bind()` method in PDOstatement: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php

There's `bindParam()`.

Comment: Thanks, @schleis, was just about to fix that.

Comment: Also is my class implementation valid @Marc B. I mean should i continue to use this dbConnect class as someone above suggested this is a wrong practice ? Your answer kick started my code.

Comment: Might as well point out there's no `fetchObjects` method either

Answer (score 2):

## You should never use a class like this

You are connectiong to database in the every method. It will surely kill your server.

Either pass a raw PDO statement around, or create a singleton if you want a class of your own

If returnValidClientId is a class method, then create a raw PDO instance and then pass it in a class constructor, assign to a class variable and use the latter all the way in methods.

Comment: I am basically trying to write an API, where i query and close the dB.

Comment: This is what you exactly SHOULD NOT